# windows 7 explorer crashes upon opening a folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash

Windows explorer restarts everytime I open the downloads folder in My Documents, I have some video files in it.

I have run virus checks but nothing has been found, also moved the files to another folder but it still happens.

Comment: Does Win7 explorer crash?

Comment: hi, just says windows explorer is restarting then goes back to desktop only my documents closes

Comment: If you have installed any latest player then try to uninstall it and then check also as suggested in answer below try to uninstall the video codec too, also check out if any corrupted video is there?

Answer (score 1):

First [turn off the thumbnail generation](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-thumbnail-previews-in-windows-vista-explorer/), then reinstall your [video codec](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_mega_codec_pack.htm). Some of the videos are either incomplete or corrupt, causing the crash. Then try re-enabling the thumbnail generation and reopen the folder. While installing the codec, you can also choose to simply not generate the thumbnail at all.

Comment: thanks I did what you said, I turned thumbnails back on and it happened again so I have just left it off

Comment: Ouch, even after reinstalling the codec? A correctly working codec shouldn't crash even if the video is invalid. Is your system 64-bit?